# Cannot focus on label

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, materialize

I have been using materializecss for quite a while and came across this problem when I'm trying to navigate my website by tabbing on my keyboard.

The checkbox for materializecss is a CSS custom checkbox, when I set the tabindex for the label of the checkbox, it only works in Firefox browsers when I uses tab.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="opt1" />
<label for="opt1" class="group1" tabindex="0">1</label>
```

Is there any to work around the issue?

Comment: shouldn't the tabindex be into the input instead of the label?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe it is a css custom checkbox. The original checkbox is put to 0 opacity. Focus on the label will associate it with the checkbox.

Comment: Chrome is full of bugs. Sorry :(

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude is there anyway to style the checkbox instead of custom ones? 
how do i customize it to have the material look?

Comment: No, the native component is not fully customizable. Your solution is made the fake checkbox as you know.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by using css.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 100px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus +label:before {
    border: 1px solid red;  
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus +label:before  {
 
    top: -4px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="opt1" />
  <label for="opt1" class="group1" tabindex="0">1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="opt2" />
  <label for="opt2" class="group1" tabindex="0">2</label>
</div>
```